# Handling null nested values when using .Select() in Lambda with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

We are having a hard time trying to figure out the best way to handle this with out declaring a loop after you get the data.

For instance take this piece of code: (Data2 is tied to Data with a foreign key)

```
context.Data.Select(_ => new DataModel
                    {
                        Id = _.Id,
                        Data2 = new Data2Model
                        {
                            Id = _.Data2.Id,
                            Name = _.Data2.Name,
                            Date = _.Data2.Date
                        },
                        Date = _.Date                                           
                     });
```

If _.Data2 is not null then this runs correctly but if _.Data2 happens to be null then this will error.  The way we are getting around this now is to add Data2Id to our DataModel and then loop through all of the records to get the information if its not null.

```
var lst = context.Data.Select(_ => new DataModel
                             {
                                 Id = _.Id,
                                 Data2Id = _.Data2ID
                                 Date = _.Date                                           
                              }).ToList();

foreach(var item in lst)
{
     if (item.Data2Id != null) 
     {
         var dataItem = context.Data2.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Id == item.Data2Id);
         item.Data2 = new Data2Model
         {
             Id = dataItem.Id,
             Name = dataItem.Name,
             Date = dataItem.Date
         }
      }
}
```

Is there a cleaner / better way to keep this in the original select loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Data2 = _.Data2 == null ? null : new Data2Model
{
    Id = _.Data2.Id,
    Name = _.Data2.Name,
    Date = _.Data2.Date
},
```

Comment: It should :) I do not have full class definition and I do not know if result is acceptable.

Comment: This worked like a charm.  The values that were null returned null and if they had data then they were returned as a new model.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the logic in separate method to shorten your LINQ query and potentially reuse your code:

```
private static DataModel Map(DataModel _)
{
    Data2Model model = _.Data2 ?? new Data2Model();
    return new DataModel
    {
        Id = _.Id,
        Date = _.Date,
        Data2 = new Data2Model
        {
            Id = model.Id,
            Name = model.Name,
            Date = model.Date
        }
    };
}
```

Your query than becomes:

```
context.Data.Select(Map);
```

You should replace the artificial types with your own.

Comment: Ill look into this method thanks.  However the answer by Pablo solved our problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
context.Data.Select(_ => new DataModel
                    {
                        Id = _.Id,
                        Data2 = _.Data2 == null ? 
                        new Data2Model{Id = _.Data2ID} :
                        new Data2Model{ Id=_.Data2.Id, Name=_.Data2.Name, Data=_.Data2.Date},    
                        Date = _.Date                                           
                     });
```

I'm making the assumption that if it is null you still have the _.Data2ID at hand?

Using the `ternary operator`

If Data2 is `null` then return a new `Data2Model` with just the other `_.Data2ID` value

If it is not `null` then go ahead and create a new `Data2Model` with all the details.